Why do jet engine vortices go toward the ground?

This image was shown to us to illustrate how a tornado forms due to a low pressure region (also see Jet engine vortices).
I find it odd that the tornado always ends up at the ground, where it is a dead end. Why not say, it orients horizontally, where there is more air available to suck inwards?

Variation of temperature with height. - How are tornadoes formed

Don't we?

I would not expect a significant temperature variation over a few feet. The tornado makes is appear that more air enters the engine from below than other directions. Is that really what happens? Why? Should we be thinking in terms of the ground being a boundary condition? If so, why doesn't a tornado form on the fuselage?

Technically, all tornadoes form horizontally in their early stages, then they're flipped over to the vertical orientation.
